# InfoPath Form Library vs. InfoPath forms on a list

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-library

What is the usage scenario's for using a dedicated Form library instead of using a custom list as where you modify the data entry form with InfoPath?

Is it if you want the added functionality you get when using the installed client instead of the web version (in SP Ent. Ed)?

In my head I would probably create a list for most cases as they are easier to work with, and I don't have to deal with adding the InfoPath logic of generating unique filenames for the form submissions.

I hope someone can enlighten me a nit here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form library generates XML documents for each entry. Whereas a custom list is simply list data with you custom entry form. Having the documents are useful of you want to interact with the forms outside of Sharepoint or if you want I do anything that isnt available in a custom list (ie. signatures).

Comment: I know it generates an xml file. And using the forms outside of SharePoint is something I would try to avoid. Web UI's are easier for most people and covers most cases. Could you elaborate on the signatures part?

Comment: When you customize the entry form for a SP list, you can only store values that have a corresponding SharePoint field type. With signatures, for example, they cannot be stored in a SP column and would be retained only in the XML InfoPath file on a forms library. Same goes for attachments inside the form or any other non-text content.